# Convert Date query on Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I want to compare two datetime fields on QueryBuilder, but first I need to convert the **datetime** format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) to **date** (YYYY-MM-DD)

How can I do this on queryBuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$yourDate = "2013-10-13 22:22:22";
$users = DB::table('users')->where('date', ">", date("Y-m-d", strtotime($yourDate)))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

.... WHERE (datetime)::date = datecompare...